# is it secure to use proxychains+tor while logged in as root

Tags: anonymity, tor, kali-linux, proxychains

when using proxychains+tor in kali,you should  be logged in as root because proxychanis doesnt work when you are not logged in as root but using tor while logged in as root is not secure so what is the correct way of using proxychains+tor,is it even possible to use these while you are not root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running those programs themselves would be *pretty safe* if they really need to run as root (I'm sure they can be ran as a normal user with the correct configuration).

What is definitely not secure is being logged in as root and running everything else as root, like a desktop environment or a web browser.